# Sort list by selecting class property name from combobox

Tags: c#, class, sorting

I have a list of objects of type `<Ticker>` like this:

```
public static List<Ticker> tickers = new List<Ticker>();
```

The `<Ticker>` objects have properties like:

```
public class Ticker
{
    public string t_TickerSymbol { get; set; }
    public int t_conId { get; set; }
    public int t_OrderId { get; set; }
    public int t_TickerId { get; set; }
    public string t_TickerMonitorName { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerAverageVolume { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerVolume { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerRelativeVolume { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerLongPeriodVolume { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerShortPeriodVolume { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerAcceleration { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerPreviousClose { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerLastPrice { get; set; }
    public double t_TickerPercentChange { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to sort the list selecting a property name from a combobox like so (pseudo-code):

```
tickers.Sort((x, y) => x[class_property_name].CompareTo(y[class_property_name]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary`, where you map the values which are displayed in your combobox with your properties:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Func<Ticker,IComparable>>();
dict.Add("Ticker Symbol",t => t.t_TickerSymbol);
dict.Add("Order Id", t => t.t_OrderId);
```

You add the keys of you dictionary to your combobox. You call sort like this:

```
tickers.Sort((x, y) => dict[comboBox.SelectedValue].Invoke(x).CompareTo(dict[comboBox.SelectedValue].Invoke(y)));
```

This will work only if your `tickers` list is not too big. It will lead to boxing and unboxing which makes you lose some performance.

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to work fine (number of tickers is always under 100); the only tweak to your code was to convert the data source for the combobox from Dictionary to List otherwise it wouldn't accept it. Now I will try it for a bit to see if it is also performance efficient. Thanks.